# How to fix scss styles leaking across pages?

Tags: javascript, css, next.js

I have a project with the following files:

```css
/* styles/1.scss */
body {
  /* Some other stuff not related to background-color */
}
```

```css
/* styles/2.scss */
body {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```
// pages/one.js
import "../styles/1.scss";

export default ()=>(
  <div>Hello, One!</div>
)
```

When visiting `localhost:3000/one` I notice that the background is blue, even though `background-color` is never styled in `1.scss`!

I believe this has something to do with css modules, so I tried wrapping `2.scss` with `:local`.
Also, I tried renaming `2.scss` to `2.module.scss`, to no avail.

How do I fix this? Thank you for your help!

Edit:
See this issue on codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-flower-oswh1

If the background is not orange, click "Go to two" then come back to one, the orange body will persist.

Comment: Try to rename it to `_2.scss`

Comment: And are you sure you're not importing 2.scss anywhere. because if is imported somewhere else where a files is in use. it would take effect.

Answer (score 1):

You need some global styles to style the body element or provide css resets.

Option 1:

```
// one.js
import Link from "next/link";

export default () => (
  <div>

    <style jsx global>{`
      body {
        background-color: red;
      }
    `}</style>

    Hello, One!
    <Link href="/two">
      <a>Go to two</a>
    </Link>
  </div>
);
```

and

```
// two.js
import Link from "next/link";

export default () => (
  <div>

    <style jsx global>{`
      body {
        background-color: orange;
      }
    `}</style>

    Hello, Two!
    <Link href="/one">
      <a>Go to one</a>
    </Link>
  </div>
);
```

You can also keep the style in a separate file and then import it where you need.

Option 2:

```
// styles/one_style.js
import css from "styled-jsx/css";

export default css.global`
  body {
    background-color: red;
  }
`;
```

and

```
// one.js
import globalStyles from "../styles/one_style";
import Link from "next/link";

export default () => (
  <div>

    <style jsx global>
      {globalStyles}
    </style>

    Hello, One!
    <Link href="/two">
      <a>Go to two</a>
    </Link>
  </div>
);
```

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-davinci-tc13t?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

I hope this helps.